# Best way to setup shared config file that contains multiple sets of properties for multiple .NET Core console application

Tags: c#, .net, console-application, configuration-files

I am using .NET Core to build a few console applications.
Each application will need to be able to use command line option to specify which geographical region to work on.  Each set of geographical region settings will include db server, db name, url, and other misc settings.

I designed a JSON config file format that looks like the following:

```
[
    {
        "region_code": "east",
        "dbserver": "dbsvr1",
        "dbname": "dbeast",
        "url": "https://....",
        "hasChapter": "true"
    },
    {
        "region_code": "west",
        "dbserver": "dbsvr2",
        "dbname": "dbwest",
        "url": "https://....",
        "hasChapter": "false"
    },
    .
    .
    .
    {
        "region_code": "southwest",
        "dbserver": "dbsvr2",
        "dbname": "dbsw",
        "url": "https://....",
        "hasChapter": "true"
    }
]
```

And I implement some code that uses `Newtonsoft.Json` to parse the file and read the settings for a given a region code.

I know that .NET Core has built-in facilities to handle configurations.  I want to know instead of writing custom code to handle it, whether there are recommended ways using the .NET Core built-in functions to handle my need.

Comment: one option i would consider is to make http request to server once region is set. server would response with appropriate settings which app would use from that moment on.

Comment: One constraint is that the web server cannot be modified, so the application will have to stick with configuration file.

Comment: you don't want to use Configuration that read the value of your setting in key-value pairs from your Jason file?

Comment: By configuration you mean the NuGet package Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration?  Can it handle the JSON layout I described above, or I have to change my file layout to make it work better with Configuration?  I would appreciate if you can show me some examples.

Comment: I still have not understood the full requirement though I will answer you on the answer section and I can give you more information.

Comment: Thanks.  I will give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Configuration providers read configuration data into key-value pairs from a variety of configuration sources.

First, you can make a class

```
   public class MiscSettings
    {
        public string region_code { get; set; }
        public string dbserver { get; set; }
        public string dbname { get; set; }
        public string url { get; set; }
        public string hasChapter { get; set; }
    }
```

And then you create an appsettings.json file or as you want. Then you can put you, Jason, you created in that file like below.

```
 {
    "miscSettings": [
        {
          "region_code": "east",
          "dbserver": "dbsvr1",
          "dbname": "dbeast",
          "url": "https://....",
          "hasChapter": "true"
        },...
        {
          "region_code": "southwest",
          "dbserver": "dbsvr2",
          "dbname": "dbsw",
          "url": "https://....",
          "hasChapter": "true"
        }
      ]
 }
```

Now in your program class, you can read your settings like below.

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json");

            IConfiguration config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
          .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", true, true)
          .Build();

            List<MiscSettings> miscSettings = config.GetSection("miscSettings")
                    .GetChildren()
                    .ToList()
                     .Select(x => (new MiscSettings
                     {
                         region_code = x.GetValue<string>("region_code"),
                         dbserver = x.GetValue<string>("dbserver"),
                         dbname = x.GetValue<string>("dbname"),
                         url = x.GetValue<string>("url"),
                         hasChapter = x.GetValue<string>("hasChapter")
                     })).ToList();

            MiscSettings settingsForEast = miscSettings.Where(x => x.region_code.Equals("east")).FirstOrDefault();
        }
    }
```

I have answered based on my understanding of your requirement. You need to add the following from nuget to your solutions.

```
Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration
Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder
Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions
Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json
```